# Failover Integration Testing of Kafka/Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I am looking at ***two*** scenarios, working on top of Spring Integration with Kafka:

1. *Happy path* - the channel flows correctly and passes it's payload to the out-bound channel successfully
2. *Alternate case* - the channel flows correctly but the out-bound channel is **down**

My plan here is to use **AOP** on the `KafkaTemplate`, that throws an Exception when it is called by any send methods. This will then be returned to the **Error Channel**.

I was wondering what other (***simpler*** & unobtrusive!) test techniques, that may be used to handle an unavailable out-bound channel?

*Bonus points* for ApplicationContext (i.e. XML) solutions, rather than annotation based!

Answer (score 0):

1. You will only get exceptions on the calling thread if `sync` is true; otherwise async failures can be emitted to an error channel (since 2.3/3.0).
2. See [Adding Behavior to Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain); specifically the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.

**EDIT**

You can also add a mid-flow gateway upstream of the channel adapter.

```
<int:gateway service-interface=OneWay error-channel="ec"
    default-request-channel="toKafka" />

public interface OneWay {

    void sendIt(Message<?> message);

}
```

The `ec` will get an `ErrorMessage` with a `MessagingException` payload, which has `failedMessage` and `cause` properties.

Comment: Thanks Gary - I have `sync` set to true so no worries there. I was hoping for a _different_ solution than AOP. Perhaps something baked into Spring Integration/Kafka?

Comment: The `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` **is** baked into Spring Integration via the `<request-handler-advice/>` child element; it does use AOP but does everything you need. An alternative is to add a mid-flow gateway upstream of the channel adapter (see my edit).